# I want to find if any message that I'm expecting to receive has not been sent to my email

Tags: gmail, gsheets

I have a set of data in the form of numbers, we'll call them RGC numbers, one column in google sheets. What usually happens is that my workmates sends me emails containing at least one RGC number somewhere in the email, typically in the body of the email.

I'm not really code savvy but I want to find out if any of the RGC numbers in my list has not been sent to my email. A text on the cell beside the number that can't be found in gmail says it is so should be fine.